# Power BI Radial Gauge charts with 2/3 value fields on TARGET VALUE

Tags: r, powerbi

I’m calculating profit on my sales: 
Is there a way to add an additional value to a Radial Gauge charts, for example, three extra value fields on TARGET VALUE? So that I can have three needles/ pointers pointing to Radial Gauge?
Trying to find a workaround  to plot two/three fields on Power BI  Radial Gauge charts
Any help with workaround will be highly appreciated, Please see the image with three Pointer which I would like to have on Radial Gauge on TARGET VALUE on Power BI at the moment Power BI can only allow one Pointer, even if this can be done using R will be highly appreciated as Power BI has R plugin.But Power BI workaround will be ideal

[Please click this link to see the Image of what I am trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STAmj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Custom Visual: Bullet Chart by OkViz for this requirement. It supports 3 target markers with control over each target marker's shape and colour.

It also uses much less space and is much easier to read that a radial gauge. You can easily present a "small multiples" table of bullet charts by adding a Category. It has many other features that are superior to a radial gauge.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380953?src=office&tab=Overview

The screenshots on that page dont do it justice - download the sample report for more live examples.